# How to check OS of the device making the api request?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I have an android and ios app. I want to check at backend programmatically that the API requests coming from the app are from the android app or ios app i.e. i want to check the platform/ OS of the user's device? Is this possible?

Comment: that would come in the User Agent string.

Comment: @iosDev82 Can it be done at backend?

Comment: @Michael Dautermann i guess i haven't used User Agent String and if i use it now and roll out an update then it won't work in previous app versions

Comment: As far as I know, User-Agent is sent along automatically when doing any HTTP requests & connections from Android or iOS to the server (and it's added in the OS layer), but I haven't investigated this too closely.  You can change the user agent string programmatically, but it's probably set to some default, which includes the device's OS version number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way on the backend.

```
 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

@GET
@Path("/get")
public Response addUser(@HeaderParam("user-agent") String userAgent) {

    return Response.status(200)
        .entity("addUser is called, userAgent : " + userAgent)
        .build();

    }

}
```

Output:

```
addUser is called, userAgent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
```

copied from [Mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/get-http-header-in-jax-rs/)